# Excel из Table 1 в Table 2

Tags: excel

Всем привет,
У меня допустим есть таблица 1 и таблица 2

Таблица 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос следующий -
2 таблицы имеют одинаковое название столбцов (не все, но часть из них)
Но строки (Date1 и Date1.1 - разные и т.д.)

Как из таблицы 2 вставить значения в таблицу 1 автоматически, и возможно ли это, если строки (в моем случае id-разные)
То есть в идеале это должно выглядеть так, я ввожу нужный id из таблицы 1 и таблицы 2(он разный но еще раз-названия стобцов одинаковые) скрипт ищет в таблице 2 нужный id, и вставляет все данные из столбцов,которые совпадают с таблицей 1, в таблицу1)

Вообще возможно ли это автоматизировать,приходится открывать две таблицы и вручную перегонять соответствующие друг-другу данные

Answer (score 0):

Для наглядности все на одном листе, создаем список соответствия id из таблицы 1 и 2 - диапазон J1:J6

В ячейку B1 вводим формулу:

```
=ИНДЕКС($A$9:$G$14;ПОИСКПОЗ(ВПР($A2;$J$2:$K$6;2;0);$A$9:$A$14;0);ПОИСКПОЗ(B$1;$A$9:$G$9;0))
```

И растягиваем на весь диапазон.

Формула работает по такому принципу:

`ВПР($A2;$J$2:$K$6;2;0)` - ищем новое название id в таблице2 из id таблицы1
`ПОИСКПОЗ(ВПР($A2;$J$2:$K$6;2;0);$A$9:$A$14;0)` - ищем номер строки из таблицы2
`ПОИСКПОЗ(B$1;$A$9:$G$9;0)` - ищем номер столбца в таблице2 по названию столбца из таблицы1
`ИНДЕКС($A$9:$G$14;ПОИСКПОЗ(ВПР($A2;$J$2:$K$6;2;0);$A$9:$A$14;0);ПОИСКПОЗ(B$1;$A$9:$G$9;0))` - берем значение из таблицы 2 (смещение от начала таблицы2 +номер строки +номер столбца) которое соответствует новому id и нужному наименованию столбца

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но id в таблице разный вот в чем проблема, но и в одной и в другой таблице есть одинаковые столбцы,как бы реализовать (и возможно ли) что я сначала указываю id из таблицы 1 потом id из таблицы 2, и он по одинаковым столбцам осуществляет замену из таблицы 1 в таблицу 2(кроме id), id должен остаться неизменным

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в вопросе вы спрашиваете: `Как из таблицы 2 вставить значения в таблицу 1 автоматически` в комментарии `и он по одинаковым столбцам осуществляет замену из таблицы 1 в таблицу 2(кроме id)` откуда и куда надо заменять? а по поводу разных id я как раз и приводил пример на моем скрине ячейки `j1:k6` это как раз список id из таблицы 1 и таблицы 2 и он оттуда и берет значения для вставки

Comment: Спасибо)) а подскажите вы для наглядности скопировали 2 таблицы на 1 лист? А можно это реализовать если Таблица 1 и Таблица 2 представлены как разные файлы

Comment: Да на 1 лист только для наглядности, данные могут быть где угодно, в т.ч. и в разных файлах, но при этом для работы они оба должны быть открыты